# I wouldn't know

Tags: traducción, definiciones, coloquialismos

Could somebody explain the sentence "I wouldn't know"? What would be a Spanish equivalent word/expression, especially in a context similar to this:

> *'Do you do this every year? **I wouldn't know**' - Leonardo DiCaprio pokes fun at Oscars drought as he has award engraved.*
>
> Leonardo DiCaprio has proved he has a sense of humour about years of being rejected by the Academy when he was overheard joking about his awards drought.
>
> The Revenant star was waiting for his award to be engraved at the Governors Ball, the Academy's official after-party, when he struck up conversation with the woman etching his long-awaited gong.
>
> "Do you do this every year?," the 41-year-old asks her. **"I wouldn't know."**
>
> [[itv.com](http://www.itv.com/news/2016-02-29/do-you-do-this-every-year-i-wouldnt-know-leonardo-dicaprio-pokes-fun-at-oscars-drought-as-he-has-statuette-engraved/)]

[Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-spanish/-was-she-annoyed-about-it-i-wouldn-t-know-) defines *I wouldn't know* as *¿Y yo que sé?*:

—Was she annoyed about it? —I wouldn't know.
—¿Se enfadó por eso? —¿Y yo que sé?

Still, *Y yo que sé* is quite rude in Spanish, so it doesn't fit the context of Dicaprio's situation. Is there any other alternative translation?

Comment: 'I wouldn't know' here may be paraphrased 'I'm not in the situation where I'm familiar with what usually happens at Oscar ceremonies, as I'm not usually invited.'

Comment: @Rathony It's DiCaprio speaking throughout.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I thought it was a conversation. It means "Since I have not come here every year and it is the first time that I received the award, I am not sure whether you did it last year or the year before."

Comment: @Rathony Yes; that's better. _Not_ the engraver replying.

Comment: Could it be paraphrased, in a grammatically better style, as "otherwise, I wouldn't have ever known/guessed"

Comment: There is no such thing as "grammatically better style". Something is either grammatical, or it isn't. But style is not binary. It's the whole reason why style exists in the first place. Because something can be perfectly grammatical and *still* someone might not like it because of personal reasons, that have nothing to do with grammar.

Comment: As to the original phrase specifically, it is fine grammatically *and* stylistically. Your rewording is grammatical as well, but stylistically worse, in addition to not being a valid rewording because that's not what the original means.

Comment: I agree with Nathalie. Being a native spanish speaker from Southamerica, makes totally sense to use "Ni idea" as an answer. This is coloquial/informal, but not an insult as MatiasAndina sugested.

Answer (score 3):

To quote what has been already explained in the comments:

> 'I wouldn't know' here may be paraphrased *I'm not in the situation where I'm familiar with what usually happens at Oscar ceremonies, as I'm not usually invited.* – Edwin Ashworth
>
> It means *"Since I have not come here every year and it is the first time that I received the award, I am not sure whether you did it last year or the year before."* – Rathony

The comment is meant to be a joke. "I wouldn't know" is a playful innuendo that hints at the fact he resents he had never won an oscar before despite his many nominations, so he doesn't know what the ceremony is concerning such an event.

Some equivalent expressions in Spanish would be:

- Y yo qué sé.
- ¿Cómo quieres que lo sepa?

You're right that would be too rude a comment to fit this case. Considering that and the fact DiCaprio isn't answering any question, a more appropriate translation would be:

- ¿Hacen/hacéis esto todos los años? Yo no tengo forma de saberlo.

The playful part of it is lost in translation, I'm afraid.

---

To explain this a little further, [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/wouldn't+know) defines *I wouldn't know* thusly:

> (I) wouldn't know: There is no way that I would know the answer to that question.

In Spanish:

> De ninguna manera podría yo saber la respuesta a semejante pregunta.

The conditional ("wouldn't know") is being used to express that if there's a cirumstance under which the speaker would actually know the answer to what they are being asked, such circumstance doesn't exist or it just isn't true. Let's take a look at an example from the same page:

- Bob: *Are there many fish in the Amazon River?*
- Mary: *Gee, I wouldn't know.*

Mary would arguably know the answer if she, say, had a passion for Amazon's fauna to the extent that she actually knew how many fish there are in the Amazon River. However, such condition is so infeasible that it's legit to say there's no way she would know the answer. In other words, if the most far-fetched condition one can think of were true, she still wouldn't know the answer. This is obviously a hyperbole, since there are some conditions that would allow Mary to know the answer, but saying there's none is a way to make her sound more contundent.

In Spanish, you wouldn't say "(yo) no lo sabría" in this case, but you can indeed say "(yo) no podría saberlo" or even "(yo) no sabría decirte". Even though it doesn't make much sense to translate it literally, the meaning is pretty much there if one does just a little mental acrobatics:

> Under no condition would I know the answer, or **I wouldn't know** the answer under any condition = Bajo ninguna circunstancia podría (yo) saber la respuesta // Bajo ninguna circunstancia sabría (yo) decirte la respuesta.

Comment: I am afraid I still can't see it. Could you elaborate it a bit more, emphasizing the role the modal verb would plays in it? Also, is the verb to know has several meanings, and it would be helpful to know what exactly it denotes, or if there's some part of the sentence has been left out but is still implied

Comment: I tried to elaborate a little bit. Is it clearer now?

Comment: I have to say, being a native speaker, it's perfectly right to say *no sabría la respuesta.* This is probably regional, but it's not excluded to rephrase it in this way.

Comment: @Ustanak Well, it is right, just not in this case. Would you translate DiCaprio's comment as "¿Hacen esto todos los años? Yo no lo sabría"? That sounds stilted to me, and I'm not sure I would understand what he's saying if I heard that. Or think of Mary's example: you could translate her answer as *No sabría la respuesta*, but that's not quite it. There's a tone of exasperation in her answer, better translated as *Y cómo podría saberlo* or even *Cómo esperas que lo sepa*. *No sabría la respuesta/no lo sabría* is a possible translation, but not the most appropriate one in this case.

Comment: @Yay In my country it's often used as *no sabría decirte*. Now you mention it, saying *no sabría* sounds empty, but saying *no sabría decirte* fills this empty.

Comment: @Ustanak Oh, that's a good one. Edited my answer to add that.

Comment: Yay: Surprised you haven't been awarded the green check mark because yours is the best answer by far.  The best part of it is when you mention that "no lo sabría" doesn't work in Spanish.  You've given so  many good answers here on this platform that I didn't question it until I read @Alejandro 's comment.  So I ran it through a couple of machine translators with the intensifier "even" to attempt to capture the sentiment in the OP's example (as in "How would I even know?!"), and, sure enough, it comes back with variations of "podría saberlo."  I'll post links in my next comment.

Comment: If you'd like to see machine translations of "How would I even know?!" you'll find some [**here**](https://www.deepl.com/en/translator#en/es/How%20would%20I%20even%20know%3F!) and [**here**](https://www.deepl.com/en/translator#en/es/How%20would%20I%20even%20know%3F!).

Answer (score 1):

@Yay did a great job of explaining the answer however I think the right tense in Spanish for this would be the ***conditional*** form, which is what "***would***" kind of is in Spanish.

Therefore, the polite/proper answer would be "No sabría". Now this sounds kind of weird by itself so you would need context based on what the question is. In the Leonardo DiCaprio example the translation would be:

> ¿Hacen esto todos los años? No sabría decirlo"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're trying to translate it literally. You can't do that.

Literal: Yo no sabría la respuesta

What he means in spanish: Ni idea

Comment: Hi, Nathalie. Welcome to Spanish Language SE! This answer doesn't seem to add anything meaningful to what has already been posted and reads more like a comment. Once you have sufficient [reputation points](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). Until then, when posting an answer please make sure you include examples and/or references to back up your claims. Also, note *ni idea* doesn't work in this case because DiCaprio isn't answering any question.

Comment: Actually, *ni idea* stands for other idiomatic thing in Spanish.

Comment: You could argue he is answering his own question.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre una pregunta retórica de uso más frecuente.

> **¿Cómo saberlo?**

Otras alternativas mencionadas por algunos son

"No sabría decirte" o "No podría asegurarlo"

Por ejemplo:

- ¿Son éstos los ingredientes de la receta de la abuela? ¿Cómo saberlo?

La traducción literal es pobre en este caso. Otras alternativas como "No tengo idea" o "Ni idea" son más comunes y más versátiles al combinarlas (informal/insulto).